# GitHub UI gives the error

Tags: git, github, tfs

It worked well for a while, then I started getting the error. If I click OK in the dialog, I see the branches in the UI and I don't see further errors.

Due to this I get the error in Visual Studio Team Explorer also. The error is '... is not a valid remote name.'.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-install GITHUB to fix this issue.